# pylint equivalent for SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, coding-style, lint

python having pylint

scala having Scalastyle

I searched around but didn't find a style checker for SQL. Does it exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require any error checker for Sql, as Sql is not a programming language. They IDE you use will help you to understand the issue in the query and can be formatted accordingly. Please choose appropriate IDE (Sql developer/ db weaver)

Answer (score 0):

I also found this sql style guide

https://www.sqlstyle.guide/

so it's more of a team wide consensus on which SQL style to go with, but not a linter to spot it out.